# Is there an equivalent Workbook_Open Event in Powerpoint VBA

Tags: excel, powerpoint, powerpoint-2007

Basically, I am trying to run some VBA code as soon as the powerpoint file is opened in windows. I don't want to run it when the presentation is started, but I guess that would be an alternative. I'm not too sure how to do that either.

In Excel I would use this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Do something here
End Sub
```

Does anyone know the alternative for Powerpoint 2007 without using an add-in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that there is a [XML option](http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/PowerPoint_Auto_Open_Code.html)

Comment: Because I fixed it :) Apparently one of the slashes was lost. And good edit Buh Buh, but I had to add that text to reach the minimum amount of changed characters.